# Json value is always string

Tags: json

Why server(CentOS 6.5, PHP5-FPM,Apache2) is returning a different json response while my Vagrant(Laravel Homestead) is throwing a right json.

Response according to Chrome Web Developer Tool.

Server Response:

```
    account_type: "1"
    activated: "1"
    additional_columns: null
    avatar_url: null
    company_name: "PRINTARABIA"
    is_admin: false
```

Homestead Response:

```
    account_type: 1
    activated: 1
    additional_columns: null
    avatar_url: null
    company_name: "PRINTARABIA"
    is_admin: false
```

Values which are type Number always treated as string, unlike on my Homestead. That is why I always have to use parseInt or parseFloat just to get the right value.

Answer (score 0):

I understand now why. I am using 5.3 and my Vagrant is using 5.6. Some say there are json bugs on 5.3 that was fixed on the following releases. Since I don't want to upgrade my server's PHP and might cause another problem. I just did another work-around which is extending Laravel's Pagination and Eloquent/Model class. In `toJson` method I just put `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`. And that's solved the problem. :) Hope I may help others who has same problem.